# How can this 74 series Inverter circuit be analyzed?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, keyboard, music, synthesizer

I'm trying to analyze the keymech scanning / sampling circuit in the WASP synthesizer

So far I understand that the keymech is sampled one key at a time by the 74 series logic driven by the dual inverter clock and I understand how the muxing works.

However in the top left of this circuit there are 4 inverters (U35A/B/C/F) and 2 SR latches (U44A/B) I'm not sure how I should analyze this section.

The input to this section (node 4 of U46C) is the logic value of the active key however this signal is connected to both the input and output of U35B by 100K unless switch U46C is activated by U33A and U35F which happens when Q3 and Q4 of U32 are both low or both high

From a functional view I think that this circuit is meant to latch the current MUX inputs through U30 when a key press is detected however Im not sure how to follow this circuit through

[image]

Comment: I would bet U35 is a 4069UB which is the unbuffered version, and is used here in its linear region (The 100k feedback resistors are typical for this).

Looks to me like U35A and 35B are some sort of monostable type arrangement, maybe designed so that the trigger will not occur every scan while a key is held down. U35C is just threshold detect and invert to get the pulse the right way up to clock a 1 into U44B.

Comment: Just as an addition to @DanMills comment about unbuffered (about which I agree), [this whitepaper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha004/scha004.pdf?ts=1637008794389&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) may be of some use.

Comment: @andowt you have more detail answer down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U35 is operating in linear mode, like an inverting amp. I believe those (4046) are from CD4000 series initially.

When the switch U46C is closed, the closed loop around U35A & U35B puts the two of amplifiers at a stable state, by creating balancing point at C47.
At this operating mode, the "input" signal (analogous to summing OPA configuration) coming through U39 & 40 & 47 sees very low impedance to the output of U35B, thus very low gain, thus less effective to output of U35B.

When the switch U46C opens, the input signal is amplified by seeing gain through R136, and positive AC feedback through C46. In turn, U35C (biased to have output low) sharply amplifies the signal, and toggles the output.

Not only CD4000 series, but 74LS00 series inverters do have (quasi) linear operating region, though narrow. In earlier days, I used 74LS04 for video amplifier.

---

Edited,

I found you are still waiting for some more. I like puzzles, and wonder why not many do. I am going to detail the answer. I know I will make mistakes, unless I can emulate or probe the circuitry. Meantime, I am not sure how much you understood what I explained already.

> However in the top left of this circuit there are 4 inverters
> (U35A/B/C/F) and 2 SR latches (U44A/B) I'm not sure how I should
> analyze this section.

U35F is an inverter that switches on/off U46C, an analog switch, not digital. What the analog switch does is to cancel (significantly reduce) the influence of the signal coming to the pin 4. 
That happens, because U46C switches on, then shorts the signal on pin 4 to the output of U35B, which is considerably low impedance compared to the source impedance of the signal on U46C-pin4. 
That assumes the keys are resistive to the touch/pressure/depth. I doubt the keys generates current with complexity. Otherwise, the circuitry does not do anything. There the sensitivity/threshold level is trimmed by P5, the 33K pot. 
When U46C opens, U35B, an inverting AMP, sees the input signal (voltage through resistance, thus current) and R136, a feedback resistor, is freed, and the signal is amplified.
U35 is just amplifying the change of U35B output voltage sharply, acquit enough to trigger U44B, that is the latched key status, pressed/depressed.

I have explained U35A & U35B, as "balancing/biasing/edge detecting" up there.

> The input to this section (node 4 of U46C) is the logic value of the active key

I am 100% sure that the input signal to U46C-pin4 is current, likely resistive pressure sensitive element driven by the reference voltage. So, it can detect the "touch".

> however this signal is connected to both the input and output of U35B by 100K unless switch U46C is activated by U33A and U35F which happens when Q3 and Q4 of U32 are both low or both high

Explained up there.

> From a functional view I think that this circuit is meant to latch the current MUX inputs through U30 when a key press is detected however Im not sure how to follow this circuit through

Yes, when the key is pressed, U30 latches the key number (which key). Except the circuitry at the top left, it is digital logic. U32 generates timing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I think my mistake was not realizing the keys would be touch sensitive - I had assumed similar to other keymechs they would be logic output. Makes much more sense now!